# Dynamic Button Creation on request by user IOS

Tags: objective-c, button

Want to know if  this is possible first I want to make a button but here's the catch. I want a user (iphone user) to create that button dynamically so in other words the user can add as many buttons as he wants in the app.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the following code to create a button

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,88,44); //The position and size of the button (x,y,width,height)
[btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Something along those lines when you want the user to add a button.